# Modifying XML Value in Custom Layout Update XML

Tags: layout-update

The word "In Stock" was added inside catalog.xml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml">
    <action method="setData">
        <name>instock_text</name>
        <value>In Stock</value>
    </action>
</block>
```

I want to rename it via Custom Layout Update XML so it would appear a different text for some products.

```
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view">
        <action method="setData">
            <name>in_stock_text</name>
            <value>This product is in stock.</value>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

The custom layout xml seems not working. Did I miss something on update xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You remove block `<block type="catalog/product_view">` from custom layout. As per magento system any function value set and child blocks assign of a block class can be managed using `<reference>` tag

```
<reference name="product.info.addtocart">
    <action method="setData">
        <name>in_stock_text</name>
        <value>This product is in stock.</value>
    </action>
</reference>
```

You can study about layout

[tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419)

[smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/30/introducing-magento-layout/)

[Magentogarden](http://www.magentogarden.com/blog/how-does-magento-layout-work.html)

Comment: Thanks @amit-bera :) However, it seems not to be working as well. I'm suspecting my theme doesn't allow to get new variable values from other areas. My temporary workaround for this one is to provide a condition if the variable is set or not. Something like this:

<?php echo $this->getInStockText() ? $this->getInStockText() : "In Stock"; ?>

Answer (score 0):

At a glance it looks like your reference name is wrong:
change product.info to **product.info.addtocart**

Comment: Doesn't work :(